# Foreach loop returns just first result

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have problem with displaying all results in foreach regarding php array.

I wrote sql query and I want it to loop trough all values returning results for each of them.

Problem is I don't know what am I doing wrong as the response returns just results for first array value (Chocolate) not for all three.

```
    $cookies = array();
    $cookies[] = 'Chocolate';
    $cookies[] = 'Vanilla';
    $cookies[] = 'Stracciatella';

    $ar = [];
    foreach ($cookies as $cookie => $value) {
        $results = $this->getEntityManager()->getConnection()->executeQuery(
            "SELECT * FROM sweets WHERE cookies LIKE :cookies",
            ['cookies' => '%"' . $value . '"%']
        );
    }
    foreach ($results as $result) {
         $ar[] = $result;
    }
  return $ar;
```

I have made this tags as the problem is not with the query but with foreach loop.

Comment: You're currently rewriting the `$results` variable on each iteration

Comment: `$ar[] = $this->getEntityManager()->getConnection()->executeQuery(…);` in the first loop, and _away_ with the second loop … (which currently does not even work, because $results is not an array, and would be superfluous anyway, becase you can easily do both things in one single loop.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're currently rewriting the `$results` variable on each iteration of your first `foreach` loop. You'll want to append your results to another variable, to then iterate through, or instead, just reduce to one `foreach` loop.

```php
    $cookies = array();
    $cookies[] = 'Chocolate';
    $cookies[] = 'Vanilla';
    $cookies[] = 'Stracciatella';

    $results = [];
    foreach ($cookies as $cookie => $value) {
        $results[] = $this->getEntityManager()->getConnection()->executeQuery(
            "SELECT * FROM sweets WHERE cookies LIKE :cookies",
            ['cookies' => '%"' . $value . '"%']
        );
    }
    return $results;
```

---

To avoid updating this and not fulfilling what you're looking for, I'll provide a few additional workflows here that you can pick and choose, and adapt to your liking. I'm not sure what CMS you're using so I'm assuming that it returns a [`PDOStatement`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.pdostatement.php) here, so I'm able to call [`fetch()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php)

**To grab a count of the cookies that match `$value`**

```php
$cookies = ['Chocolate', 'Vanilla', 'Stracciatella'];
$counts = array_fill_keys($cookies, 0);
foreach ($cookies as $cookie => $value) {
    $counts[$cookie] = $this->getEntityManager()->getConnection()->executeQuery(
        "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM sweets WHERE cookies LIKE :cookies",
        ['cookies' => '%"' . $value . '"%']
    )->fetch();
}
```

**To get the cookie data and count the results:**

```php
$cookies = ['Chocolate', 'Vanilla', 'Stracciatella'];
$sweets = []; // previously $results
$counts = array_fill_keys($cookies, 0);
foreach ($cookies as $cookie => $value) {
    $sweet = $this->getEntityManager()->getConnection()->executeQuery(
        "SELECT * FROM sweets WHERE cookies LIKE :cookies",
        ['cookies' => '%"' . $value . '"%']
    );
    $sweets[] = $sweet;
    $counts[$cookie] += 1;
}

// This gives you:
print_r($sweets); // the data
print_r($counts); // the counts
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I have just one question? How can I separate results as they are all in $results array? @Reece

Comment: What do you mean by "separate"? Are you looking to have 2 variables with the same data in, one for preserving and one for manipulating / editing?

Comment: I want to pull data for each of the 'tastes' so I could count them separate. @Reece

Comment: Sorry if I'm interpreting incorrectly, but if you're wanting to count the number of sweets related to the `$value` (taste, I'm assuming?), then you would want to use `COUNT(*)` in your query. Otherwise, if you want both the count and the data, you could store it into a multi-dimensional array. I can provide an example for the latter if preferable?

Comment: You're the boss. :)  I just want 'taste' with count number. :) @Reece

Comment: @gisem1990 I've updated my answer with some suggestions, which assume that `executeQuery` returns `PDOStatement`, allowing for the use of `fetch()`